# Samsung NP300E5E imposible to access BIOS

Tags: windows, bios

I have Samsung NP300E5E laptop and i would like to install fresh version of Windows. But i have read lots of comments about issue with these laptops... Basically hard drive was formatted that means recovery directory's is lost When i trying access in to BIOS (i need to change startup priority and change something with security settings) but i can't because F2 is not working (should be F2 because this is on official website) also other combinations not working. Everything what can i see is Samsung logo and then after few seconds laptop reboot This is not duplicate question and i don't have recovery disks

Answer (score 3):

Bump to old question. I had the same problem with my old Samsung NP300E5X (NP300) (BIOS version P07RAC). I have changed something in BIOS (I guess something to do with secure boot or UEFI, anyway I don't know what's the difference, sorry) and it was impossible to enter to BIOS by F2 button.
Problems were like:

- you can't enter to BIOS by pressing F2, but you can enter Windows
  Recovery Mode (F4 or F10, nothing interesting here to solve the
  issue),
- you can't update BIOS by Samsung BIOS update utility, because you
  have already got the latest version (utility stops working saying
  this),
- shorting RTC reset, BIOS crisis contacts gives no effect
  (contacts next to RAM on the motherboard), • external USB-keyboard
  gives no effect,
- if you disconnect any HDD - your notebook is just stuck in endless bootloop (you see Samsung logo-F2-for-BIOS-F4-for-Recovery, 3-2-1, reboot). No way you can enter BIOS here.

What your aim should be: **to reset all BIOS settings to default**. We are going to reflash the same version P07RAC, but without Samsung BIOS update utility.

1. Open the BIOS update tool from Samsung. Click on «Download» instead of «Update». It offered "ITEM_20130402_1070_WIN_P05RAJ.exe" (I don't know, why there is "RAJ" not "RAC", but this is for NP300E5). If you have a different notebook, the file name should be something like that, so, keep Googling your needed «ITEM_..._version.exe».
2. Run the file "ITEM_20130402_1070_WIN_P05RAJ.exe". The program decompresses several files to "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Temp__Samsung_Update" The program refuses to update the BIOS because it is the latest version, and then deletes the files. I copied the files before closing the program. They contain the ROM and the SFlash64.exe utility, and some other files required for flashing.
3. Run cmd.exe as an Administrator and run this exe from copied files SFlash64 /n /s /sa /ips /exit /file P07RAC.rom (notice, here "P07RAC" not "P05RAJ). Also, you may check "SFlash64 -help" for help. This will flash over the BIOS with the same version resetting all settings. So, you can enter BIOS by F2 button as normally. Summarized from here: http://forum.notebookreview.com/threads/where-is-the-lid-closure-sensor-on-a-series-5-ultra-np530u3c.683727/#post-9455595

Comment: For anyone who same problem.
These steps requires you to run exe on the pc. And If you don't have access to Windows follow these steps. Create a Live Windows USB, which allows to start windows installation from USB. Then you can start the USB by clicking F9 button on boot, even if BIOS is deleted. Now you have full windows enviroment to run Samsung BIOS update tools.

Answer (score 0):

The last versions of Windows use a kink of "protected boot" (UEFI) that, in some situations, can disable the access to Bios. I have a Samsung notebook too, and the only way to gain access to the BIOS was removing the hard drive, plugging it on another machine and erasing ALL partitions. 
Be careful with that because, if your notebook has a original Windows licence, you can end up loosing it. 
Before anything, I would create a backup copy of ALL partitions in the HDD using appropriate tools.
Regards,
MiroGen

Comment: All my partitions has been deleted. And i have create another two.

Comment: I tried already to install another windows version on another machine but still not working on samsung...

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. Finally clicked on something that worked. I booted to Win 10 install media, went to repair clicked on UEFI settings, boom rebooted to bios settings. Hope this works for others.